# Server Side Events not always sent to client in timely manner

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am implementing server side events in ASP.NET. Things seem to mostly work. However, sometimes events are not sent to the client right away. Sometimes the previous event is sent to the client.

I have found numerous references to this problem. The problems appears to be compression. Turning this off in web.config with

```
<urlCompression doDynamicCompression="false" />
```

is the only way I have found that seems to work consistently.

Surely there must be a better way. Is there?

**Please do not tell me to use SignalR**; that would not be an answer to my question.

-- Update --

Here are some links to similar issues:

[ASP.NET Web API: PushStreamContent flush does not flush](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29793308/asp-net-web-api-pushstreamcontent-flush-does-not-flush)

[PushStreamContent stream does not flush under load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24565246/pushstreamcontent-stream-does-not-flush-under-load)

https://www.justinribeiro.com/chronicle/2014/04/09/sse-asp-net-mvc-double-message/

http://blog.differentpla.net/blog/2012/07/14/streaming-http-responses-in-net/

Comment: please can you share some code and information about the project framework, so we can reproduce it?

Comment: Sounds like the compressor isn't flushing. You could try using a reverse proxy for your compression.

Comment: I think it is a timing issue.  Compressing data just make the transfer quicker and avoid a timing issue.  How often are you sending data, the size, and what type of delay are you seeing.

Comment: are you using iis? if so theres some settings you need to change.

Comment: @Aron Yes, it isn't flushing. If you have a solution to make it flush, please let me know.

Comment: @jdweng It seems to be a compression issue.

Comment: @DanielA.White Yes, I'm using IIS. Yes, I changed the setting as stated in the question above. Seems like there should be a better way.

Comment: I just think compression is just shorten the transfer time and changing the timing.

Comment: You could try either using a reverse proxy like caddy for the compression. Or use .net middleware to implement the compression... Then you can flush the buffers manually.

Comment: You could also push large amounts of white text to IIS to overflow the compression buffer. The RLE should mean that the white text uses minimal bandwidth. But you really don't have control over IIS, it was also not designed for multipart HTTP response.

Answer (score 0):

After trying many things:

- ChunkedEncoding
- BaseStream.Flush
- NoBufferPolicy
- [Disabling compression in Web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40839265/1478)
- [Changing uploadReadAheadSize and others in Web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24565246/1478)
- Even closing the connection, which worked and auto-reconnected but was naassttyy

I ended up just setting a small buffer size on the `StreamWriter` using the constructor overload (128bytes which is the smallest amount you can set), then after my message and before the `Flush` I just wrote some whitespace.

```cs
await client.WriteLineAsync( "".PadLeft( 128 ) );
await client.FlushAsync();
```

This works locally but also on Azure App Service which is where I was experiencing the problem (it always worked fine locally on IISExpress).

Here is my simple service class to manage this; bear in mind that I wanted to send messages to specific users based on the production of externally generated  reports which pinged my asp.net app when complete; hence the use of a Dictionary of stream connections for each user (each user could have multiple tabs open so might have many connections).

One thing I have left to sort out is to keep the connections open as Azure App Service closes any connection after 2 minutes.

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Simple writer class to store the valid state of a client stream connection
    /// </summary>
    public class ClientWriter
    {
        public ClientWriter( StreamWriter writer )
        {
            Valid = true;
            Writer = writer;
        }

        public bool Valid { get; set; } = true;
        public StreamWriter Writer { get; set; } = null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Manage client messages using Server Sent Event (SSE) Messages protocol
    /// </summary>
    public class ClientMessageService : IClientMessageService
    {
        public ClientMessageService( ILogger logger )
        {
            _jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
                Formatting = Formatting.None,
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            };
            _logger = logger;
            _messageEncoding = new UTF8Encoding( false );
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Subscribe a user session/tab with the system to receive messages
        /// </summary>
        public HttpResponseMessage SubscribeUser( int userId, HttpRequestMessage request )
        {
            _logger.Info( $"Subscribing connection for user {userId}" );

            var response = request.CreateResponse();
            response.Content = new PushStreamContent( ( stream, content, context ) =>
            {
                OnStreamAvailable( userId, stream );
            }, new MediaTypeHeaderValue( "text/event-stream" ) );

            _logger.Info( $"Returning connection subscription response for user {userId}" );
            return response;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Unsubscribe a user and dispose of all open connections
        /// </summary>
        public void UnSubscribeUser( int userId )
        {
            if( Subscribers.TryRemove( userId, out var clientConnections ) )
            {
                foreach( var client in clientConnections )
                {
                    client.Valid = false;
                    if( client.Writer != null )
                    {
                        client.Writer.Dispose();
                        client.Writer = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sends a message to all open sessions for the given user
        /// </summary>
        public async Task PostMessageAsync( int userId, ClientMessageBase message )
        {
            _logger.Info( $"Posting message to user {userId}" );

            if( Subscribers.TryGetValue( userId, out var clientConnections ) )
            {
                // Send notifications to all valid client connections
                foreach( var client in clientConnections )
                {
                    if( client.Valid )
                    {
                        _logger.Info( $"Posting message to user {userId} client for type {message.Type}" );
                        await WriteEventDataAsync( client, message.Type, JsonConvert.SerializeObject( message, _jsonSerializer ) );
                    }
                }

                // Cleanup any invalid/bad client connections
                foreach( var client in clientConnections )
                {
                    // Dispose of any invalid/bad connections
                    if( client.Valid == false && client.Writer != null )
                    {
                        client.Writer.Dispose();
                        client.Writer = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Send given data message to client connection
        /// </summary>
        private async Task WriteEventDataAsync( ClientWriter client, string eventType, string data )
        {
            try
            {
                if( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( eventType ) )
                {
                    await client.Writer.WriteLineAsync( $"event:{eventType}" );
                }
                await client.Writer.WriteLineAsync( $"data:{( data ?? "" )}" );
                // Must end the data event with a new line to separate events from each other
                await client.Writer.WriteLineAsync();

                // Because flush doesn't appear to flush the underlying stream as noted
                // a lot on StackOverflow and other sites, the best solution is to pad out
                // the buffer to force a flush of the actual message data
                await client.Writer.WriteLineAsync( "".PadLeft( 128 ) );
                await client.Writer.FlushAsync();
            }
            catch( Exception )
            {
                // Connection might not exist; tab or browser might have been closed
                // So mark it as bad for cleanup later once all notifications have been
                // sent
                client.Valid = false;
                _logger.Error( $"ERROR: Failed to post message for type {eventType}" );
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a stream writer connection and store against the user for future
        /// </summary>
        private void OnStreamAvailable( int userId, Stream stream )
        {
            _logger.Info( $"Creating connection stream writer for user {userId}" );

            var clientWriter = new StreamWriter( stream, _messageEncoding, 128 )
            {
                // Force to unix endings
                NewLine = "\n",
            };
            var client = new ClientWriter( clientWriter );

            if( Subscribers.TryGetValue( userId, out var clientConnections ) )
            {
                clientConnections.Add( client );
            }
            else
            {
                var clients = new ConcurrentBag<ClientWriter> { client };
                Subscribers.TryAdd( userId, clients );
            }

            _logger.Info( $"Created connection stream writer for user {userId}" );
        }

        private readonly Encoding _messageEncoding;
        private readonly JsonSerializerSettings _jsonSerializer;
        private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, ConcurrentBag<ClientWriter>> Subscribers = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, ConcurrentBag<ClientWriter>>();
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
    }
```